# Canvas element not updating

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I am trying to visualise a reinforcement agent moving through a 2d grid.  I coded up a visualisation using canvas, and everytime my agent makes a move I try to update the grid.  I was hoping to see an animation, but instead I see nothing until the agent has completed all this moves and I see the final state.  If I step through with Google Chromes Developer tools then I can see the individual steps.  I do not think it is a problem of my code just running to fast, because each step takes a couple of seconds.

My implementation is as follows, with the function `gridWorld()` called once to create a new object and `executeAction` called every time I want to draw.  As shown I have used `ctx.save()`, and `ctx.restore()`, but that is only an attempt to solve this problem, and it seems to have made no difference.

Thanks

```
var execute gridWorld = function(action) {
   var canvas = document.getElementById("grid");
   this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   this.executeAction = function(action) { 
      this.ctx.save()
      // ... Do reinforcement learning stuff
      // For every cell in grid, do:
         this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(244,0,0)"
         this.ctx.fillRect(positionX, poisitonY, 10,10)

      this.ctx.restore();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the code takes a long time to execute, the browser will not update the display until there is an actual break in the code. Use `setTimeout()` to cause a break in code execution whenever you want the canvas to update.

Comment: Thanks but I am uncertain of how to work with this.  In my execute action function I replaced the drawing code with setTimeout(draw, 15). But it seems the draw function does not get called after 15 milliseconds but instead they all get called after the main code has finished executing (i.e. the same problem as before).  Also the drawing code depends upon the state of the agent, how can I be sure what this state will be if it is called out of sequence?

Comment: `[execute code to draw first frame][wait][execute code to draw second frame][wait]` etc... The previous frame need to use a `setTimeout` on the function that draws the next frame. If your code is not set up by frame then you need to change it so it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your not going to see animations because they are happening way too fast. You need to break them up like in the following example.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/smvcn/)**

If I did something like this for example

```
for(x = 0; x < 256; x++){
    player.x = x;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,256,256);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillRect(player.x,player.y,4,4);
}
```

You would only ever see the player at the end of the board every time that function is called, and you wouldn't see any of the animations in between, because the loop runs too fast. Thats why in my live demo I do it in small increments and call the draw every 15 milliseconds so you have a chance to actually see whats being put on the canvas.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question I dont think it is that my code is to fast (since their is significant computation happening every loop).  Instead I think the main loop is somehow blocking the update of the screen.  I have tried to use setTimeout to get around this to no success, as described in my comment to the answer above.  Thanks

Comment: @zenna in order for someone to help you were going to have to see more of the code or an example. Just so you aware however in a loop you will *never* see an update to canvas unless you break out of it, in a for loop you will *never* see the updates that happen within the for loop fyi.